# How to run selenium script on server

Tags: python, selenium, vps

I have a question.
Is it possible to run a python script, which using selenium to scrape the data from dynamic website, on server(amazon ec2).
I trying to find some info about this a lot of times, but this is without results.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT 2024:** `chrome_options=` updated to `options=` to support latest version.

---

Servers don't use GUI/Windows and they even don't have monitors.
It is called 'headless' server (because monitor looks like server's head)

Selenium runs web browser which needs GUI/Windows to display its window.

But some web browsers can also run without displaying window - they can run `headless`.

```
 from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options  

 chrome_options = Options()  
 chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  

 driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)  # `chrome_options=` converted to `options=`
```

For Firefox should be similar code.

There was also Selenium's webdrive [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) which worked headless but it is not developed any more.

Linux has also program [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) which can create fake/virtual monitor on headless computer and it could run programs which can't run without GUI/XWindows.

I didn't check it but one of this method may work on Amazon EC2.